# Xamarin.Forms WebAPI JsonConverter.DeserializeObject unhandled exception

Tags: c#, json, api, xamarin, serialization

I'm trying to replicate the functionality in one of MoshHamedani's course on Xamarin Forms.
Here's my code (with a valid, working _url, that returns a json object with escape characters):

```
public partial class PartnersListPage : ContentPage
  {
    private const string _url = "xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz";
    private HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
    private ObservableCollection<Partner> _partners;

    public PartnersListPage()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
      var jsonObject = await _httpClient.GetStringAsync(_url);
      var dotNetObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Partner>>(jsonObject);

      _partners = new ObservableCollection<Partner>(dotNetObject);

      partnersListView.ItemsSource = _partners;

      base.OnAppearing();
    }
```

Partner.cs looks like this:

```
public class Partner
  {
    //public int Id { get; set; }
    //public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string WebUrl { get; set; }
  }
```

Postman returns the following:

```
{
    "partners": [
        {
            "imageUrl": "http://www.abcdefgh.xy//media/1007/3.jpg",
            "webUrl": "http://www.abcdefgh.xy/"
        },
        {
            "imageUrl": "http://www.ijklmnop.xy//media/1009/5.jpg",
            "webUrl": "https://www.ijklmnop.xy/xy"
        },
        {
            "imageUrl": "http://www.qrstuvxy.xy//media/2623/slsp.svg",
            "webUrl": "https://www.qrstuvxy.xy/"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I hit the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject line, I get the following:
An unhandled exception occured. **Why** is it not working?

Comment: Please include a screenshot of the exception.

Comment: when you get an UnhandledException, you need to put a try/catch block around the code in question to catch the exception - then you can figure out what the specific exception cause is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are deserializing with incorrect type (`List<Partner>`)
I'm using [Json to c#](http://json2csharp.com/) converter in order to determine the class I need - just paste in your json text/data and in will generate the classes for you. For the example for your json text/data you need:

```
public class Partner
{
    public string imageUrl { get; set; }
    public string webUrl { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Partner> partners { get; set; }
}
```

........

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

controller returning single object but you are trying to array deserialize

```
public class Partner
  {
    //public int Id { get; set; }
    //public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string WebUrl { get; set; }
  }

public class ApiResult
{
    List<Partner> Partners {get;set;}
}
```

and..

```
var dotNetObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResult>(jsonObject);
```

Comment: - Thank you for your answer, but I need you to be a little bit more specific. I need more of a kind of a step-by-step help.

Comment: I could use a little (lot) more clarification... could you re-post the entire final code?  I'm not able to work out "Partners" in "ApiResult".